# Python how to wait till a reading has settled using lists?

Tags: python

I have a reading that im trying to take, I have to wait an indeterminate amount of time until the value is stable (+/- a few ms).

Im putting each reading into a list...any thought how I can break the while loop when I have had 10 consecutive samples that are +/- a few ms?

Heres so far:

```
    takeReading = False
    readingSamples = []

    while takeReading == False:
        readingSamples.append(read7700DifDelay('127.0.0.1',8,1))
        time.sleep(5)
        print(readingSamples)
```

Comment: What library does `read7700DifDelay` come from. Doesn't it have some kind of way of checking whether the request has finished?

Comment: Are you just trying to break when you get 10 samples, just when len(readingSamples)>=10?  Or do you need the relative change in samples values to be small (thus stable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the slice `[-10:]` to get the last ten readings, then compare the `min` and `max` of those. (You also might want to check that there are at least ten samples so you don't `break` after the very first one.)

```
while takeReading == False:
    readingSamples.append(read7700DifDelay('127.0.0.1',8,1))
    time.sleep(5)
    last_ten = readingSamples[-10:]
    if len(last_ten) == 10 and max(last_ten) - min(last_ten) < a_few_ms:
        break
```

Comment: I think its working an absolute treat :) Ive put int in a while 1 loop thanks so much!

Comment: I do have one question, is it possible to used a standard deviation piece of maths to get a better idea of when something is stable? My maths is very poor :(